# Angular Custom Validator Unit Testing Failing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, customvalidator

The validator is as follows :

```
import { AbstractControl } from "@angular/forms";



export function ValidateInt(control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null {
 
  function countPlaces(value) {
    var text = value.toString();
    var index = text.indexOf(".");
    return index == -1 ? 0 : (text.length - index - 1);
   }

  function checkNumeric(value) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(value)) && isFinite(value);
  }
  let controlValue = control.value.toString();
  let trailingDec = controlValue.indexOf('.') == -1 ;
  let decimalCount = countPlaces(control.value) ;
  let isNumeric = checkNumeric(control.value) ;

 if(isNumeric == false ){
    return { 'int': true };
  }else if(trailingDec == false){
    return { 'int': true };
  }else{ return null}

}
```

The Test File is as follows :

```
import * as intValid from './intValidator.validator' ;
import { AbstractControl, FormControl, Validators} from "@angular/forms";


describe('validate int', () => {
    var intControl : AbstractControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
        intControl.setValue(23) ; 
    
    fit('returns true', () => {
      let actual = intValid.ValidateInt(intControl);
      expect(actual).toEqual(null);
    });
});

describe('validate int', () => {
  var intControl : AbstractControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
      intControl.setValue(23.) ; 
    let badReturn = { 'int': true};
    fit('returns false', () => {
      let actual = intValid.ValidateInt(intControl);
      expect(actual).toEqual(badReturn);
    });
});
```

The error is :

```
validate int returns false FAILED
        Error: Expected null to equal Object({ int: true }).
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the test fails, when I follow the control flow in the debugger with breakpoints as the solution is running, the proper control with 'INVALID' is returning.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be this :

```
intControl.setValue(23.) ;
```

Changing to :

```
 intControl.setValue('23.') ;
```

Allowed the test to pass.... d'oh! Type issue